# Mapping over multiple functions in JAX to speed up for loops

Tags: python, jax

I am currently trying to speed up some JAX code I have been writing and see if I can replace two of my for loops with faster equivalents.

The first loop grabs a function from a list and evaluates it on the corresponding element of the input (3D) arrays `xs` and `ys` and modifies the input arrays before passing the next slice into the next function:

```py
for j in range(N):
    dx, dy = mass_models[j].alpha(
        xs[j],
        ys[j],
        kwargs=kwargs[j]
    )
    weights = etas[j].reshape(-1, 1) # make this a column vector
    xs = xs - weights * dx
    ys = ys - weights * dy
```

I tried using `jax.lax.scan` because the input is updated for each loop run, but I couldn't figure out how to map each loop run to a different function.  It is also tricky because I need to pass different `kwargs` to each function.

The next loop might be a bit easier, the first axis of the `xs` and `ys` from above are each mapped to a different function and the results are stacked (again with different `kwargs` for each function).  At the moment I am using list comprehension:

```py
results = jnp.stack([
    light_models[j].surface_brightness(
        xs[j],
        ys[j],
        kwargs[j],
        pixels_x_coord=pixels_x_coord[j],
        pixels_y_coord=pixels_y_coord[j]
    ) for j in range(N)
])
```

Is there a more JAX friendly way to write these kinds of loops?

Edit:
For context `xs` and `ys` are JAX arrays, `kwargs` is a list of dictionaries (these are the parameters that are being estimated by the fitting code that uses this), `pixels_*_coord` are lists.  `mass_models` and `light_models` are lists of class instances.

Comment: Whether this can be translated to a `jax.lax.scan` or other jax looping/batching operation depends entirely on the contents of the various things (lists? arrays? dicts?) that you're indexing into. I'd suggest editing your question to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but that is still not enough information to answer the question. It fully depends on the call signatures of the functions you're mapping over, whether those functions are jit-compatible or not, and on the contents of the lists and dictionaries you mention. Without a minimal reproducible example, the only possible answer to your question is "maybe, or maybe not".